# Pi-hole logging with client names

Tags: networking, router, dns, ip, pihole

## Situation

I am using Pihole in a network with a google wifi router. The router (`...1.1`) is configured to use the Pihole server (`...1.220`) for DNS lookup, and all is working as wanted. So far, so good.

My question is related to the following observation: the router does not tell the clients that the DNS server can be found at `...1.220`, but rather at `...1.1`. The router forwards the lookup, and from the perspective of Pihole, all requests seem to come from the router:

[image]

## Goal

**Instead of the routers IP address, I'd like to see the client device names.**

**Is that possible?**

## What I've done / read / seen

I have read [here](https://discourse.pi-hole.net/t/how-do-i-show-hostnames-instead-of-ip-addresses-in-the-dashboard/3530) about two options. However, they both involve manually maintaining a list of IP reservations.

> "Just make a reservation for every device on your network."

That is not an option in my case, as it's too much work and new devices register with the network all the time.

From where I'm standing, I don't see why the following process cannot be implemented:

1. A new device registers on the network.
2. It is given an IP address by the DHCP server - be it the router's or the Pihole's - and its self-reported name is stored.
3. Whenever this IP address does a lookup (during the time the IP remains tied to the device), its name can be shown in the table.

Am I seeing that wrong? If not, is there a reason this is not yet implemented? After all, the local IP address is not useful information, as the device it's connected to continuously changes.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/GoogleWiFi/comments/p0h4wu/turn_off_dhcp_on_google_wifi_to_use_another_dhcp/ workaround

Comment: Give pihole a static IP address.     Change the DHCP address pool to issue 1 IP address which is the same IP as your Pihole's static IP.
    Enable DHCP on the PiHole.    Set the DNS of the router to use whatever you want as DNS.

Comment: For bonus points, install unbound https://docs.pi-hole.net/guides/dns/unbound/

Comment: Thanks for than link @Gantendo. Does that show the client's hostnames automatically or do I need to manually add a name each time a new mac address is connecting to the network?

Comment: I went ahead with the instructions in the reddit post, and can report that yes, the client names show up without additional manual effort. So, thanks for the link!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

1. In google wifi, set an IP reservation for the pihole server. If you have additional IP reservations, write them down and delete them.
2. In google wifi, set the DHCP range to 1 address, namely, the IP address in step 1.
3. In pihole >> settings >> set DHCP on. Pick an IP range outside that does not include the router and the pihole server.
4. If there were additional IP reservations that you deleted in step 1, add them here in pihole.
5. Reboot google wifi and the pihole server for good measure.

Now the devices get their IP address from pihole, use pihole directly for their DNS lookup, and if they have a public visible name, they show up with that name in the query log.